# Sci-fi short story: Humans have achieved immortality through regeneration, looking for suicide pills

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Looking for a Sci-Fi short story that could be part of a collection.

The plot is about how humans achieve a sort of immortality through regeneration, but the bad side effect is overpopulation. Humans still feel pain and have scars, and wars, so they are looking for a suicide pill.  I remember a character in the story, a man, who is covered in scars and possibly the more scars one has, the older they are.

Comment: I assume it's NOT the Star Trek episode "Mark of Gideon" or a novelization thereof?

Comment: Nope...good episode, but the one I am trying to remember was definitely a short story, maybe in a little anthology of sci-fi short stories...another story in the collection had to do with humans evolving past their physical forms - that story had a concept I remember too: dogs had kept up with humans for awhile, but we soon out evolved them too -it was about how limitless our boundaries are - a positive story.

Comment: The story I'm looking for about immortality and scars may have had a love story...a man and a woman.  The setting is really key (very dystopian) and describes how the earth was overpopulated because humans figured out how to live longer by regeneration...bad side effect was that it was really hard to kill them and when they started running out of room or food, wars began...

Comment: I cannot remember the book, author or title...please help!  I wanted to use the short story as an example in my masters thesis and have to cite it.

Comment: This story is not  PERCHANCE TO DREAM
by Sally A. Sellers

Comment: It's a fairly popular theme. 2BR02B is how one civilization dealt with the issue.

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61704/scifi-book and I MAY be able to offer some tips.